# How to properly install additional C header files in VS 2022

Tags: c, header-files, lib

Recently started messing with C and found that ncurses.h and dirent_win.h exist, but vs does not have it internally, i have found a few ways and sites but is there any site and method that is reccomended for getting such libraries.

I tried looking for ways to install but mostly found stuff for linux so not sure what to do since i am using win10

Comment: https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.h` files are not libraries, and even if you include them it will not allow you to use functions and data types declared there. You need also a source code of the library or a compiled library.

For windows I would rather recommend something less Linux-centric like https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses

You will need to clone the repo and build the library.

Comment: " `.h`  files are not libraries," ... too true.  But the internet is getting saturated with every kind of reference to "filename.h library".   It's a pandemic of sorts, and I predict we're going to see a lot more of it before it gets better.

Comment: i see, gonna use PDCurses then

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the answers wasn't really answered, i mainly asked for help on how to make these header/libraries availible on my machine for my own use

Comment: @NajLitarvan - fair enough, all I was doing is checking. You would be surprised how may people ask a question, get an answer, grab the answer and go and never indicate the question was answered. It then stays in the SO unanswered question list forever. If, in your opinion, additional answers may be helpful, by all means, wait until a reasonable amount of time has passed and you are satisfied nothing further is coming. You may also leave a comment prompting for additional information that may turn this response into a complete answer. All completely up to you.

Comment: @NajLitarvan so you basically want someone to teach you how to use git, VS, how to manage solutions and projects in it. SO is not a teaching portal and imagine how much time would it take to write the complete tutorial.